# Why can't compiler calculate size of array in case passing 2D array by reference

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction

Just wondering - i've written following function

```
template <class T, size_t N>
T* asFlatArray (T arr[][N])
{
    // some code
}
```

and call it like

```
asFlatArray(myArray); // where myArray is int myArray[some_size][sime_size];
```

compilation runs without errors. But if i change 'arr' to reference like

```
template <class T, size_t N>
T* asFlatArray (T (&arr)[][N])
{
    // some code
}
```

i'll have errors:

```
parameter ‘arr’ includes reference to array of unknown bound ‘T [][N]’
```

I know how to fix it

```
template <class T, size_t Rows, size_t Columns>
T* asFlatArray (T (&arr)[Rows][Columns])
```

but i don't understand why is it's happening?

Comment: No, it's not about VLA

Comment: @JarrodRoberson The OP's right, the question asks for why the 1st array dimension cannot be deduced by the compiler at compile time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that the first function template is equivalent to

```
template <class T, size_t N>
T* asFlatArray (T (*arr)[N]) {}
```

so there is no dimension to calculate. It will match a pointer to an array, or anything that can decay to pointer to array. Thus is can also match 2D array.

As for the second example, a reference or pointer to type `T[][N]` cannot be a function parameter, which leads to a compiler error. Of course, you can add an extra template parameter for the missing dimension:

```
template <class T, size_t N, size_t M>
T* asFlatArray(T (&arr)[N][M]) {}
```

Comment: Thanks, it explains all

Comment: The type `T[][N]` exists and it is called "array of an unknown bound of arrays of size `N` of `T`". And you can create a reference to it, see [a demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37c7f3aac6781794)

Comment: @AntonSavin Thanks. I re-phrased the relevant sentence.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 and C++14 standards in part `[dcl.fct]/8 (8.3.5)` explicitly state:

> If the type of a parameter includes a type of the form “pointer to array of unknown bound of `T`” or “reference to array of unknown bound of `T`,” the program is ill-formed.

There is actually a [core language active issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#393) proposing to remove that from the standard, so  perhaps we won't see it in C++17.

BTW, if the array size is really unknown, clang (but not gcc) compiles the code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    static int arr[][3];
};

// this compiles on clang but not gcc
void func(int (&arr_ref)[][3]) {
    std::cout << arr_ref[1][2] << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int (&arr_ref)[][3] = A::arr;

    std::cout << A::arr[1][2] << std::endl;

    arr_ref[1][2] = 100;
    std::cout << A::arr[1][2] << std::endl;

    arr_ref[1][2] = 200;
    func(arr_ref); 
}

int A::arr[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a60d4da47a0e7035)

Comment: Your example is incorrect, because templates are instancing if (and only if) they are using in code. Look at this http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3377561217a520b8

Comment: @Kastaneda I've already realized it and removed the example from the answer.

Comment: yes, sorry, i don't saw your redaction while written my comment